# Overriding all Access form control AfterUpdate methods

Tags: vba, event-handling, ms-access

I have a set of custom event handlers for all my textboxes and combo boxes. The reason for this is my users want the bound form (to SQL Server) to **immediately** push changes to the recordset, rather than the normal "Save" idea of an Access form. This is the constraint I have to deal with.

As a result, what I am doing is in each form open method I initialize event handlers for the form. I could not find a way to basically override the "default control event handler" and instead have to override *each* event handler for *each* type.

In each of the form_current event I want this functionality for I have:

```
mCustom_FormCurrent me
```

Which points to the following method:

```
Public Sub mCustom_FormCurrent(ByRef p_form As Form)
    Set m_EventHandlerManager = New EventHandlerManager
    m_EventHandlerManager.initFormHandlers p_form.Form
End Sub
```

This sets up a custom event handler for all objects. I put this on the `form_current`

Class: `EventHandlerManager`

```
Public Sub initFormHandlers(p_form As Form)

    Dim ctl
    
    'types - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa224135(v=office.11).aspx
    
    
    Dim txt As EH_TextBox
    Dim cbo As EH_ComboBox
    
    Set m_TextBoxes = New Collection
    Set m_ComboBoxes = New Collection
    
    For Each ctl In p_form.Controls
        
        Select Case ctl.ControlType
        
            Case acTextBox:
                Set txt = New EH_TextBox
                txt.init ctl, p_form
                m_TextBoxes.Add txt
            Case acComboBox:
                Set cbo = New EH_ComboBox
                cbo.init ctl, p_form
                m_ComboBoxes.Add cbo
                
            Case default:
            
        End Select
    Next ctl
    
End Sub
```

I have two classes related to this. I structured the EventHandlerManager in such a way as to allow easy addition of other form controls which are also bound (right now I am only concerned with ComboBoxes and TextBoxes).

Class: `EH_ComboBox`

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Private WithEvents m_cboBox As Access.ComboBox
Private m_frm As Access.Form
Private Const Evented As String = "[Event Procedure]"

Public Sub init(p_src, ByRef p_frm As Access.Form)
'As Access.TextBox
    Set m_frm = p_frm
    Set m_cboBox = p_src
    m_cboBox.OnChange = Evented
    
End Sub


Private Sub m_cboBox_Change()
    
    On Error GoTo m_cboBox_Change_Error

    Dim i As Integer
    i = 0
Application.Echo False
    m_frm.Recordset.Edit
    m_frm.Recordset.Update
Application.Echo True

    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Sub

m_cboBox_Change_Error:
    'This resolves an error which happens sometimes - not sure why Resume works but it fixes the .Update causing errors ???
    If i = 0 Then
        i = i + 1
        Resume
    Else
        Application.Echo True
        sendErrorEmail "m_cboBox_Change for " & m_cboBox.Name, err.Description, err.Number, ERROR_DEBUG
    End If
End Sub
```

Class: `EH_TextBox`

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Private WithEvents m_txtBox As Access.TextBox
Private m_frm As Access.Form
Private Const Evented As String = "[Event Procedure]"



Public Sub init(p_src, ByRef p_frm As Access.Form)
'As Access.TextBox
    Set m_frm = p_frm
    Set m_txtBox = p_src
    m_txtBox.OnExit = Evented
    m_txtBox.OnChange = Evented
    m_txtBox.BeforeUpdate = Evented
    m_txtBox.AfterUpdate = Evented
End Sub

Private Sub m_txtBox_AfterUpdate()

    On Error GoTo m_txtBox_AfterUpdate_Error

    Dim i As Integer
    i = 0

    m_frm.Recordset.Edit
    m_frm.Recordset.Update
    
    
    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Sub

m_txtBox_AfterUpdate_Error:
    'This resolves an error which happens sometimes - not sure why Resume works but it fixes the .Update causing errors ???
    If i = 0 Then
        i = i + 1
        Resume
    Else
        sendErrorEmail "m_txtBox_AfterUpdate for " & m_txtBox.Name, err.Description, err.Number, ERROR_DEBUG
    End If
    
End Sub
```

---

### What I am looking for

How can I make this better? This feels like a huge hack, which it kind of is, but barring the use case which is causing this how can I better create custom event handlers for all form controls? I'd have to make a class for **each** for control I want one for. In my situation there are only two, so it's not "that bad."

Ideally, the form controls would all be inherited from a `BaseFormControl` class (I made the name up) I could override the `AfterUpdate` for in a generic sense, and then apply to *all* form objects. This does [not seem to exist](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21466989/1048539) though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First some general remarks about the code, and then an alternative way to go about this.

- Underscores have a special meaning in VB. They indicate event procedures and implementations of an interface. You should remove them from your namings. It's a bit confusing to look at. Particularly this.

  > ```
  >  Private Sub Form_Current()
  >     mCustom_FormCurrent Me
  > End Sub
  > ```

  It really looks like you're calling an event procedure that resides in the form, but that's not what is actually happening.
- Also naming issues, I don't like the `p_` prefix you're using for parameters. They're locally scoped, so there's no need to prefix them. As a VBA dev, I've come to expect that kind of prefix to mean it's module scoped, like your `m_` prefix.
- The use of `On Error GoTo 0` doesn't do anything in this code. That statement disables the error handler in a routine, but you use it directly before exiting. Thus, it doesn't do anything and can be safely removed.
- In the `EventHandlerManager` class, you don't declare a type for `ctl`.

  > ```
  > Public Sub initFormHandlers(p_form As Form)
  >
  >     Dim ctl
  > ```

  This means it's being implicitly declared as a variant. It would be better to declare it as an `Access.Control`. (But stop what you're thinking, `Control` doesn't support events...)
- Script Labels are (necessarily) scoped to their procedure. So, there's no need to spell them out like you have.

  > ```
  > On Error GoTo m_cboBox_Change_Error
  > ```

  This would work just as well and be less clutter.

  ```
  On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
  ```

  Also, if they're standard, you can write code to insert these snippets for you.
- I don't like how you're trying to `Resume` in your error handlers. I mean, it's okay if it's working for you, but it would be better to take note of the specific error that needs to be retried for and only retry if it's that particular error. You may want to add more behavior later where it wouldn't be a good thing to simply retry.

  Also, you should rename `i` to something like `errorCount` and declare it much closer to where you're using it. Also note that there's no need to set the value to zero. An integer's default value is already zero.

  ```
  Private Sub mTextBox_AfterUpdate()

      On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

      mParentForm.Recordset.Edit
      mParentForm.Recordset.Update

      Exit Sub

  ErrorHandler:
      'This resolves an error which happens sometimes - not sure why Resume works but it fixes the .Update causing errors ???
      Dim errorCount As Long
      If errorCount = 0 Then
          errorCount = errorCount + 1
          Resume
      Else
          sendErrorEmail "mTextBox_AfterUpdate for " & mTextBox.Name, Err.Description, Err.Number, ERROR_DEBUG
      End If

  End Sub
  ```
- [There is zero benefit to ever declaring an Integer type in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26409520/3198973). Use a `long` type instead.

---

Okay, now let's talk about a better way to do this.

> Ideally, the form controls would all be inherited from a
>   BaseFormControl class (I made the name up) I could override the
>   AfterUpdate for in a generic sense, and then apply to all form
>   objects. This does not seem to exist though.

You're absolutely right. Inheritance would be an ideal way to deal with this. Unfortunately, in VBA we can either have inheritance, via interfaces, or events. We can't have them both. So, we'll need another option. Being that you're goal is to not have to create a class for each different type of Access control, I took the following approach. It does have it's cons however. This works only under the assumption that you want all controls to behave exactly the same. Personally, I like your original approach, as it allows you to create controls that react differently to the same events.

1. I created an `EhControl` class and copied all of the logic from your two existing control classes. This removed some duplication in declaring the `Evented` constant and parent form class variable.
2. I created a private initialize routine for each type of access control.
3. Create a public initialize control that takes in an `Access.Control` instead of a `TextBox` or `ComboBox`.
4. Move the `Select Case` logic into the public `Initialize` method.

**EhControl.cls**

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Private Const Evented As String = "[Event Procedure]"

Private mParentForm As Access.Form
Private WithEvents mTextBox As Access.TextBox
Private WithEvents mComboBox As Access.ComboBox

Public Sub Initialize(ByRef source As Control, ByRef parentForm As Access.Form)

    Set mParentForm = parentForm

    Select Case source.ControlType
        Case acTextBox:
            InitializeTextBox source
        Case acComboBox:
            InitializeComboBox source
        Case Default:
            'do nothing
    End Select

End Sub

Private Sub InitializeTextBox(ByRef source As TextBox)
    Set mTextBox = source
    mTextBox.OnExit = Evented
    mTextBox.OnChange = Evented
    mTextBox.BeforeUpdate = Evented
    mTextBox.AfterUpdate = Evented
End Sub

Private Sub InitializeComboBox(ByRef source As ComboBox)
    Set mComboBox = source
    mComboBox.OnChange = Evented
End Sub

Private Sub mTextBox_AfterUpdate()

    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    mParentForm.Recordset.Edit
    mParentForm.Recordset.Update

    Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
    'This resolves an error which happens sometimes - not sure why Resume works but it fixes the .Update causing errors ???

    Dim errorCount As Long
    If errorCount = 0 Then
        errorCount = errorCount + 1
        Resume
    Else
        'sendErrorEmail "mTextBox_AfterUpdate for " & mTextBox.Name, Err.Description, Err.Number, ERROR_DEBUG
        MsgBox "Textbox AfterUpdateError"
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub mComboBox_Change()

    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    Application.Echo False

    mParentForm.Recordset.Edit
    mParentForm.Recordset.Update

    Application.Echo True

    Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
    'This resolves an error which happens sometimes - not sure why Resume works but it fixes the .Update causing errors ???

    Dim errorCount As Long
    If errorCount = 0 Then
        errorCount = errorCount + 1
        Resume
    Else
        'sendErrorEmail "mTextBox_AfterUpdate for " & mTextBox.Name, Err.Description, Err.Number, ERROR_DEBUG
        MsgBox "Textbox AfterUpdateError"
    End If
End Sub
```

*Note that there is now an opportunity to extract a subroutine for your error handlers. I have not done this.*

1. Next I created a new `ControlEventRegister` class. (`EventHandlerManager` was a bit much for my taste.)
2. As I stated earlier, the logic in the select case has been removed, so this class is responsible for nothing more than looping through the form that gets passed to `InitializeEventHandlers` initializing and adding them to a single `mControls` collection.

**ControlEventRegister.cls**

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Private mControls As Collection

Public Sub IntializeEventHandlers(parentForm As Form)

     Set mControls = New Collection

     Dim eventedControl As EhControl

     Dim ctl As Control
     For Each ctl In parentForm.Controls
        Set eventedControl = New EhControl
        eventedControl.Initialize ctl, parentForm
        mControls.Add eventedControl
     Next ctl
End Sub
```

Lastly, I wasn't a fan of the sub you had in a regular module to call the `EventHandlerManager`. I think you could run into some bugs if more than one form was open at a time. I'm not sure, but I don't think it's too much of a burden to add the following code to your forms.

**Form Code Behind**

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Private mEventManager As ControlEventRegister

Private Sub Form_Current()
    Set mEventManager = New ControlEventRegister
    mEventManager.IntializeEventHandlers Me
End Sub
```

Comment: Ahhh, that way is definitely easier to handle all the events in one class. I never realized you could do something like that, I was trying to think of it as an inheritance thing - never occurred to me that you could setup multiple WithEvents in a single class. You've got a much more streamlined setup here than I did that's for sure!

Comment: The downside is that it could easily turn into the "one class to rule them all."

Answer (score 2):

Your class has a memory leak: both the form object and the associated event handler object will never get cleared by the garbage collector (well, I'm not 100% sure on where the reference to `EventHandlerManager` gets stored, but I'm sure it doesn't get cleared and thus the form object doesn't get cleared).

I outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53011097/7296893) on Stack Overflow how you can get reference loops on forms in Microsoft Access because the form object doesn't get deallocated when the form closes if there are open references to it.

Your reference loop works in the following way: the form has a reference to the class `EventHandlerManager`, `EventHandlerManager` has a reference to `EH_TextBox` and `EH_ComboBox`, `EH_ComboBox` and `EH_Textbox` have a reference to the form.

There are several ways to deal with this. One is to listen to form events in your `EH_Textbox` and `EH_ComboBox` classes, and remove the reference to the form on the `Form_Unload` event. However, I'd break the loop in the `EventHandlerManager` class to avoid redundant code.

**EventHandlerManager.cls**

```
Private WithEvents m_frm As Access.Form

Public Sub initFormHandlers(p_form As Form)
    Set m_frm = p_form
    m_frm.OnUnload = "[Event Procedure]"
    'Your existing code
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Unload(Cancel As Integer)
    'Release event handler collections
    Set m_TextBoxes = Nothing
    Set m_ComboBoxes = Nothing
End Sub
```

<sub>I'm new on code review, if this just should be a comment redirecting to an explanation of the bug on SO, please notify me and I'll delete it, if not feel free to edit this notice out</sub>